# OpenGL 3.3. Indexed sprite only displaying first color of palette. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, palette

I am trying to create a retro sprite type environment in OpenGL 3.3. More specifically, with the use of palettes. From the sources I have found and used, everything should be good. And yet it isn't. My sprite keeps ignoring the indexed pixels and just uses the first colour it finds in the palette.

Sources:

- [Paletted textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Paletted_textures)
- [Answer to related question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43294/creating-a-retro-style-palette-swapping-effect-in-opengl/43313#43313)

**Source code:**
[In case you want to run it you can download and build the source code through this link, it uses CMake and is compatible with Windows and Unix](https://github.com/DoctorBownes/PaletteProblem)

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

GLFWwindow* _window = nullptr;
GLuint vertex_buffer = 0;
GLuint uv_buffer = 0;
GLuint shaderProgram = 0;

void SetupWindow() {
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    _window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "PaletteProblem", NULL, NULL);

    if (_window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(_window);

    if (!gladLoadGL()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLAD.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
    }
}

void SetupVertexandUV() {
    GLfloat VertexBuffer[12]{};

    VertexBuffer[0] = -0.5f;
    VertexBuffer[1] =  0.5f;

    VertexBuffer[2] =  0.5f;
    VertexBuffer[3] =  0.5f;

    VertexBuffer[4] =  0.5f;
    VertexBuffer[5] = -0.5f;

    VertexBuffer[6] =  0.5f;
    VertexBuffer[7] = -0.5f;

    VertexBuffer[8] = -0.5f;
    VertexBuffer[9] = -0.5f;

    VertexBuffer[10] = -0.5f;
    VertexBuffer[11] =  0.5f;

    GLfloat UVBuffer[12]{};

    UVBuffer[0] = 0.0f;
    UVBuffer[1] = 0.0f;

    UVBuffer[2] = 1.0f;
    UVBuffer[3] = 0.0f;

    UVBuffer[4] = 1.0f;
    UVBuffer[5] = 1.0f;

    UVBuffer[6] = 1.0f;
    UVBuffer[7] = 1.0f;

    UVBuffer[8] = 0.0f;
    UVBuffer[9] = 1.0f;

    UVBuffer[10] = 0.0f;
    UVBuffer[11] = 0.0f;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * 4, VertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &uv_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uv_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * 4, UVBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

GLuint TextureSampler = 0;
GLuint PaletteSampler = 0;

const char* vertex_shader =
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec2 vertexPosition;\n"
"layout(location = 1) in vec2 uvPosition;\n"
"out vec2 UV;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition.x ,vertexPosition.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"   UV = uvPosition;\n"
"};\0";

const char* fragment_shader =
"#version 330 core\n"
"in vec2 UV;\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;\n"
"uniform sampler1D myPaletteSampler;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   vec4 index = texture2D(myTextureSampler, UV);\n"
"   vec4 texel = texture(myPaletteSampler, index.r);\n"
"   FragColor = texel;\n"
//" FragColor = texture2D(myTextureSampler, UV);\n"
"};\0";

void SetupSpriteandPalette() {
    //Drawing a smiley face where: the body should be red, eyes should be green and mouth should be blue
    char indexedsprite[8 * 8]{
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,
        0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,
        0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,
        0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    };

    glGenTextures(1, &TextureSampler);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureSampler);

    //For testing the sprite without using the palette, only un-comment when FragColor = texture2D(myTextureSampler, UV);
    //for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    //    indexedsprite[i] *= 85;
    //}
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, 8, 8, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexedsprite);
    
    //Setting up a palette of four colors in an RGBA format
    char PaletteColors[4 * 4]{
        //RED
        255,
        0,
        0,
        255,

        //GREEN
        0,
        255,
        0,
        255,

        //BLUE
        0,
        0,
        255,
        255,

        //YELLOW
        255,
        255,
        0,
        255,
    };

    glGenTextures(1, &PaletteSampler);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, PaletteSampler);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, 12, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PaletteColors);

}

void SetupShaders() {
    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;


    // Compile Vertex Shader
    GLuint VertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(VertexShader, 1, &vertex_shader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(VertexShader);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShader, InfoLogLength, nullptr, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    GLuint FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(FragmentShader, 1, &fragment_shader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShader);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShader, InfoLogLength, nullptr, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    // Link the program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, VertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, FragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, InfoLogLength, nullptr, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    glDeleteShader(VertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShader);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLuint Init;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &Init);
    glBindVertexArray(Init);
}

void DrawSprite() {

    GLuint vertexPositionID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertexPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        vertexPositionID,   // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        2,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    GLuint uvPositionID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "uvPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvPositionID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uv_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        uvPositionID,   // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        2,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionID);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(uvPositionID);
}

int main(void) {
    //Setting up the window, along with safety checks
    SetupWindow();

    //Setting up the shaders, along with safety checks
    SetupShaders();

    //Setting up the vertices and UVs for the sprite
    SetupVertexandUV();

    //Setting up the sprite and palette data
    SetupSpriteandPalette();

    do {

        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Drawing the sprite and setting up the Vertex-Position and UV-Position
        DrawSprite();

        glfwSwapBuffers(_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    } while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(_window));
    return 0;
}
```

What I get:
[image: Result of the code above]

What I expect:
[image: Desired result]

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

I have tried setting the glActiveTextures.

I have tried changing the format values.

And I have tried changing sampler types.

Comment: Basically, you've asked the same question before: [OpenGL, paletted textures not working. What am I missing here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184157/opengl-paletted-textures-not-working-what-am-i-missing-here). You have got a nice answer pointing out the problems in your code. Why did you not apply the suggestions from the answer to your code, but repeated the question? The problem is still the same.

Comment: @Rabbid76 perhaps because it was closed and deleted  so if OP had any issues with that they couldn't get further help

Comment: @Rabbid76 I did apply them, I tried every suggestion. But it was all to no avail. I am starting to think this method of pixel colouring is just not feasible. So as a last stand, I wanted to try and ask one more time. This time with the entire source code included.

Comment: You should not include the entire source code, but [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, do not repeat a question, but edit and improve the original question.

Comment: Look, obviously I am not making any friends here by this action. I am sorry. I'll delete the question and won't do anything again.

Comment: No do not delete this question! Can you please keep your questions instead of deleting them permanently. You have received an answer. Please read it carefully. (Keep it in mind and do better next time)

Comment: Alright, I will. Thanks for the advice 

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems I see in your code.

First, you create the palette texture of size 12, but initialize it with an array that has only four texels. You should fix that:

```
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4 /*HERE*/, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PaletteColors);
```

Second, and the most important issue, is that when you sample your sprite in the shader you'll be getting a float in the 0 to 1 range rather than 0 to 255. Then this will be scaled to the 0 to 4 range when sampling the palette texture. For the small numbers you have in your sprite (0 to 2), you'll end up sampling your palette at location 0 to 2/255*4 = 0.0313; with the nearest neighbor interpolation this is rounded the 0th entry of your palette.

To solve this you can undo the scaling that OpenGL does:

```
"   vec4 index = texture2D(myTextureSampler, UV);\n"
"   vec4 texel = texture(myPaletteSampler, (index.r*255 + 0.5)/textureSize(myPaletteSampler).x);\n"
"   FragColor = texel;\n"
```

A better approach might be to use an integer texture for the sprite (`GL_R8UI` with `GL_RED_INTEGER` and `usampler2D`) to disable the scaling when sampling, and use `texelFetch` for the palette to disable the scaling when reading the palette. You'll need to check though if these features are available in OpenGL 3.3.